# What do you call the term when you set the variable to a method?

Tags: python, methods, syntax, nonetype

```
from tkinter import *              
root = Tk()        
button1 = Button(root, text= "Hello world click here to close")   
y = button1.pack()         
print (type (y))      
root.mainloop()
```

When setting `y` to `button1.pack()`, what do you call that technique and why does it return "<class 'NoneType'>"?

Comment: Because you set the variable to the return from the function call `pack()`.  You probably wanted to leave off the parentheses so it wasn't a call.

Comment: So you can set a variable to a function call? I try to look up this topic, but most of them talk about setting a variable to a container or variable to a class, but not variable to a function call. I see some of the Python tutorials write like this style in their code: <var> = <function call>.

Answer (score 1):

`y = button1.pack()` sets `y` to an expected returned value from the `pack()` method.

For example,

`foo = random.randint()` sets `foo` to the random number returned by the `randint` method.

`foo = random.randint`, however, assigns the `randint` method to the variable `foo`

Since this method does not return anything, y has no value, and `type()` indicates as such

What you want to do is use `y = button1.pack`, which will assign that function to `y`

If you run `type()` on `y` after that, you will see that it returns it's type as "function"